# rails 4 strong params + dynamic hstore keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hstore, strong-parameters

I'm having a problem overcoming the new strong params requirement in Rails 4 using Hstore and dynamic accessors

I have an Hstore column called `:content` which I want to use to store content in multiple languages, ie `:en, :fr`, etc.  And I don't know which language upfront to set them in either the model or the controller.

```
store_accessor :content, [:en, :fr] #+226 random other il8n languages won't work.
```

How can I override strong params (or allow for dynamic hstore keys) in rails 4 for one column?

```
  params.require(:article).permit(
    :name, :content,
    :en, :fr #+226 random translations
  )
```

Short of...

```
params.require(:article).permit!
```

which of course does work.

Comment: how does layout look like for this dynamic hstore data ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to whitelist a hash of dynamic keys. You can use some `ruby` code as follows to do this:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:name).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:content] = params[:article][:content] 
end
```

This worked for me, hope it helps!

Comment: how would i allow any set of keys, rather than whitelisting. for example, if i want to allow the user to create his key names: Here is my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054535/setting-hstore-in-rails4-dynamic-key-values

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing something similar and found this to be a bit cleaner and work well.

Assuming a model called `Article` you can access your `:content` indexed `stored_attributes` like this: `Article.stored_attributes[:content]`

So your strong params looks like this:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:name, content: Article.stored_attributes[:content])
```

Assuming your params are structured like: { article => { name : "", content : [en, fr,..] } }

Answer (score 0):

As people have said, it is not enough to permit the :content param - you need to permit the keys in the hash as well. Keeping things in the policy, I did that like so:

```
  # in controller...

  def model_params
    params.permit(*@policy.permitted_params(params))
  end  

  # in policy...

  def permitted_params(in_params = {})
    params = []

    params << :foo
    params << :bar

    # ghetto hack support to get permitted params to handle hashes with keys or without

    if in_params.has_key?(:content)
      content = in_params[:content]
      params << { :content => content.empty? ? {} : content.keys }
    end
  end
```