# Rails 4 Dynamic generate Hstore keys and automatically add it into whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, hstore

I have a `cgi_attributes` hstore type column in the UrlCommand model.

```
class UrlCommand < ActiveRecord::Base
    store_accessor :cgi_attributes, :name, :range, :security, :default_value
end
```

However, the keys in `cgi_attributes` should be dynamically added by users.

And I also want to render each key as a input filed in my form

Rather than hard-code the columns

```
  - [:name, :range, :security].each do | column |
    = render :partial => 'attributes' , :locals => { f: f, column: column }
```

And also need to add those dynamically generated key can be update into my Model.

```
def url_command_params
  params.require(:url_command).permit(:model_name, :firmware_version, :cgi_attributes,
                                       :cgi_name,:name, :range, :security)

end
```

Now, All of my code are based on hard-code, How to make the keys and value can be dynamically added by users and store into the UrlCommand model ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348703/rails-4-strong-params-dynamic-hstore-keys

Comment: @deep it doesn't mention how to access those key via ActiveRecord.

Comment: I have the same problem. store_accessor needs to be changed dynamic and how to show/save such hstore data

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a separate table for the attribute names (CustomAttributes) and then create a loop that adds  them with `store_accessor` like this:

```
CustomAttributes.all.each do |attribute|
     store_accessor :cgi_attributes attribute.name
end
```

I guess you can do something similar to strong parameters. I have not tried this my self, because I'm struggeling to get hstore working in my application. But i will have the same user situation/ problem to solve. So i will test it and change my answer once i get it working and confirmed.

a bit like it is explained in this railscast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms