# Rails4 PG hstore Unpermitted parameters: data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Rails4 app using PG hstore.

This is from the console:

[image]

This is the Vehicle Controller:

```
    def vehicle_params
      params.require(:vehicle).permit(:description, :stufftype_id, :name, :tenant_id, :count, :manufacturer, :man_date, :purchase_date, :purchase_price, :current_price, :warranty_date, :model, :notes, :site_id, :sell, :loaned, :borrowed, :sell_to, :borrowed_from, :sale_id, :sale_price, :sold_amount, :sold, :archive, :vendor_id, :loaned_to, :data)
    end
```

It contains `:data`

So, why is data an unpermitted parameter?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you permit `:data` in your strong parameters, it only permits scalar value.

Scalar values can be of type `String`, `Symbol`, `NilClass`, `Numeric`, `TrueClass`, `FalseClass`, `Date`, `Time`, `DateTime`, `StringIO`, `IO`, `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` and `Rack::Test::UploadedFile` as described in the strong parameters documentation:

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#permitted-scalar-values

It means that passing a `Hash` for `:data` in the params hash, will not be permitted as is.

What you are looking for is a way to permit nested parameters. Also described in the documentation:

https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#nested-parameters

And if your hstore keys are dynamic, you can whitelist the dynamic hash yourself using the method described in the following SO question:

[rails 4 strong params + dynamic hstore keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348703/rails-4-strong-params-dynamic-hstore-keys)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - I used the `rails 4 strong params + dynamic hstore keys` answer.