# Rails 5 - how to whitelist the param for an ENTIRE jsonb postgres column in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, parameters, whitelist

I have tried to use the suggested example [from github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454#issuecomment-14167664). You can also find it on some answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects?rq=1) for Rails 4.

I have tried this in Rails 5.0.1 and I just get an empty hash {} stored in the database:

```
def proposal_params
  params.require(:proposal).permit(:document, :account_id).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:document] = params[:proposal][:document]
  end
end
```

Obviously if I just do permit! it works.

I also tried an answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348703/rails-4-strong-params-dynamic-hstore-keys?rq=1):

```
def proposal_params
  params.require(:proposal).permit(:account_id, document: Proposal.stored_attributes[:document])
end
```

but that also does not work.

The :document attribute contains json which is never the same between requests...and is a long and complex structure.

I just need to dump it as is into a jsonb column.

For the curious, here is an example of what can be in `document`:

```
{
   "document":{
      "customer":{
         "id":"273a0ad1-0867-4c17-8e0a-3284c6f2f6af",
         "first_name":"Ricardo",
         "last_name":"Bird",
         "email":"ricardo_bird@smithtrantow.co",
         "mobile":"07786560223"
      },
      "state":8,
      "salutation":"Mr & Mrs Bird",
      "total_price":0,
      "quoted_products":[
         {
            "product":{
               "sku":"9111",
               "name":"Solid European Oak",
               "price":25.99,
               "category":"Wood",
               "sub_category":"Solid",
               "updated_at":"2016-12-01",
               "updated_by":"Donald Duck",
               "created_at":"2016-11-01",
               "created_by":"Mickey",
               "image_url":"http://www.higherground.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/wood-flooring-thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            "total_price":25.99,
            "total_area":1,
            "product_total_price":25.99,
            "is_manual_total":false,
            "is_installed":false,
            "install_price":null,
            "are_rooms_grouped":false,
            "rooms":[
               {
                  "name":"Dining Room",
                  "icon_url":"assets/fb-img/dining-room.png",
                  "number":null,
                  "area":1,
                  "width":null,
                  "length":null,
                  "subfloor_prep":null,
                  "subfloor_price":null,
                  "perimeter_product":null,
                  "perimeter_length":null,
                  "is_perimeter_installed":false,
                  "perimeter_price":null,
                  "perimeter_style":null,
                  "is_perimeter_remove_old":false,
                  "is_move_furniture":false,
                  "move_furniture_price":null,
                  "move_surcharge":null,
                  "stairs_stepcount":null,
                  "surcharge":null,
                  "is_installed":false,
                  "uplift_price":null,
                  "install_method":"bonded"
               }
            ],
            "is_extras":true,
            "threshold_count":2,
            "radiator_count":3,
            "trim_count":2,
            "threshold_price":30,
            "radiator_price":4,
            "trim_price":10,
            "is_rear_mat":false,
            "is_front_mat":true,
            "front_mat_type":"Coloured",
            "rear_mat_type":null,
            "front_mat_area":2,
            "front_mat_price":60.01,
            "rear_mat_area":null,
            "rear_mat_price":null,
            "extras_total_price":212.01999999999998
         }
      ],
      "status":"Draft",
      "is_details_oneprice":false,
      "notes":"Testing submission"
   }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is a PR outstanding to provide an easy solution to this here: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26308

Comment: Could this issue be related to the warning "Unpermitted parameter: document" you get when trying to permit the `document` parameter?

Comment: @Pyro Your answer solved it. Thank you! I think the unpermitted parameter message might just be a red herring in this particular case.

Comment: Great to hear. Oddly your function returns the same result for me, I'm not entirely sure this fixes the cause of the problem. The impending pull request you linked to probably does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm correct you still need to `permit!` the document parameter:

```
def proposal_params
  params.require(:proposal).permit(:account_id).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:document] = params[:proposal].fetch(:document, ActionController::Parameters.new).permit!
  end
end
```

The way this works is that it will only keep the `account_id` at first but then within `tap` we add the `document` parameter back by trying to retrieve it from the original parameters. `ActionController::Parameters.new` as the default value for `fetch` ensures that the `permit!` method is always callable even if no `document` parameter has been passed.

Under the hood [`ActionController::Parameters#permit!` seems to recursively call the `permit!` function](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionController/Parameters/permit%21) on the contained parameters as well, so we can call it on any instance:

```
def permit!
  each_pair do |key, value|
    Array.wrap(value).each do |v|
      v.permit! if v.respond_to? :permit!
    end
  end

  @permitted = true
  self
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This works, thank you. I added a comment to the question to note that there is a solution coming in a future version of Rails to simplify the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
to_unsafe_hash
```

See:

http://eileencodes.com/posts/actioncontroller-parameters-now-returns-an-object-instead-of-a-hash/

Comment: Thanks for the link, I didn't realise parameters now return an object.